# WordPress installation on localhost/virtual hostname redirects to wordpress.org (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: wordpress, apache

I'm trying to set up a local WordPress development environment using Apache on Ubuntu 22.04. I followed these two tutorials:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-a-lamp-stack
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-22-04

Here's my virtual host configuration (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/your_virtual_host.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin d3@gmail.com
  ServerName wordpress.dev
  ServerAlias www.wordpress.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
  <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem:

1. When I access localhost, a blank page loads.
2. When I access wordpress.dev or [www.wordpress.dev](http://www.wordpress.dev), it redirects to wordpress.org.
3. When I access localhost/wp-config.php, I see gibberish code instead of the expected content.
4. Accessing localhost/wp-login.php displays login form source code.

What I've tried:

```
Restarted Apache with sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I've searched online but haven't found a solution that addresses these specific issues. Any help would be appreciated!

Additional Information:

```
Ubuntu version: 22.04
```